# How to ' pass concatenated parameters as single parameter and populate the view page'?

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried and got help from stack overflow kind team member and reached till this level, yet I have to go step closer to solve it .However, when
I am trying to pass parameter that is concatenated,  example I pass parameter like l/59.  Once this parameter is passed, it should retrieve relevant data from table named  st_dak_details , and I want data retrieved from that table   to  populate it in another view page . But it is not working, meaning not getting populated.

**first view page where I pass parameter**

```
<div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" >Reset <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="getbtn" onclick="loadPagcontente('<?php echo site_url()?>/UsermanagementController/forwardtrack')" >Get Detais <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="getbtn" onclick="loadPagcontente('<?php //echo site_url()?>/UsermanagementController/forwardtrack')">Get Detais <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button> -->
</div>
```

**Inside Controller**

```
function forwardtrack($param='',$param2='') {
    if(sizeof($this->db->get_where('st_forward',array('letter_no' =>$param.'/'.$param2))->result_array())>0 && (!($param.'/'.$param2) )){
       $data1['message']= 'notallow';
       $this->load->view('track1',$data1);
    }else{
       $data1['name']=$this->db->get_where('bpas_user_profiles',array('AgencyMainParentID' =>$this->session->userdata('ministryId'),'AgencyParentID'=>$this->session->userdata('parentID'),'AgencyID'=>$this->session->userdata('agencyID')))->result_array();

       $data1['userdeatils']=$this->ag->tracks($param.'/'.$param2); 
       $this->load->view('userManagement/forward2', $data1);
    }
   /* ag=> agency model */
}
```

**Inside model**

```
public function tracks($letterno="")
{   
     $query= $this->db->get_where('st_dak_details',array('dakLetterNo'=>$letterno));
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
      } else {
            return array();
      }
}
```

**Inside  final view page**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>forward to
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post" id="forwardmessage">


                <div class="form-group">
                   <label  for="letter"class="col-xs-12 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">letter_no: </label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>

                    <?php  if(!empty($userdeatils)){
               foreach($userdeatils as $row) { ?>
   <!--  your html code -->

                     <input name="dakLetterNo" id="dakLetterNo" value="<?php echo $row['dakLetterNo'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>



                </div>




                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">created: </label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="copy_to" id="copy_to" value="<?php //echo $userdeatils->created;?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>   -->

                   <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label">Attachment: </label>
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> 
                        <input type="file" name="Attachment" id="Attachment">
                   </div>    
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Subject: </label>
                      <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="subjecterr"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="subject" id="Remark" value="<?php echo $row['Remark'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />   

                     </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Place: </label>
                     <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="place" id="place" value="<?php echo $row['place'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />  
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">from: </label>
                   <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="from" id="receieve_add" value="<?php echo $row['receieve_add'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">


                     <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Created: </label>
                   <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="created" id="created" value="<?php echo $row['created'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>
               </div>

                <!-- </div> -->

                <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->


                     <!-- <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Message: </label> -->
                   <!-- <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> -->
                     <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span> -->
                     <!-- <input name="message" id="message" value="<?php //echo $userdeatils->created;?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required /> -->
                   <!-- </div> -->

                <!-- </div> -->
                 <?php } ?>  <!-- //foreach close -->
                 <?php } ?>  <!-- //if close -->

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Message: </label>
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> 
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                        <span id="messageerr" class="text-danger"></span>
                   </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                        Forward to
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <select name="forwardto[]" id="agency" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                           <?php 
                           foreach($name as $row):  ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $row['cid']?>">
                                <?php echo $row['FirstName'].$row['MiddleName'].$row['LastName']?>
                              </option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        </select> 
                        <span id="forwarderr" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <button type="button" onclick="addmessageto()" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>
                         <button type="button" onclick="removemessageto()" class="btn btn-warning">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span id="addmoreforwardto"></span>
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-12 col-md-12"> 
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="forwardmessage('forward')"> <i class="fa fa-send"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Forward to</button>

                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="forwardmessage('complete')"> <i class="fa fa-send"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Complete Action</button>
                      <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Settings/view_ods_dashboard/"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                      <i class="fa fa-dashboard" aria-hidden="true"  ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dashboad</span>
                      </button>
                    </a>
                   </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect concatenated  parameter  that I passed from first view page to retrieve data from table and populate it into the final view page.

Comment: show us your table data with `l/59` value

Comment: 1/59 doesn't seem like a valid anything to query with. how do you plan on sending this to the second controller? and i assume param1 and param2 means you want to split it to 1 (param1) and 59 (param2)? please fix your formatting and make your question more clear, removing unnecessary code.

Comment: @M.Hemant, the table name is  'st_dak_details' and one of the column name is 'dakLetterNo' with 'varchar' as data type. Inside the column 'dakLetterNo'  I have inserted data l/54 or l/59 ..via Ajax code: like this :$('#filename').append($('#letterNo').val()+'/'+(parseInt(data)+1)); which produces l/59 where '/ ' is considered as a  string.

Comment: @Alex, thank you for your kind concern.

Comment: did you try like condition in it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data like `l/54` or `l/59` with varchar datatype column then below query will work.

```
public function tracks($letterno="")
{   
      //$query= $this->db->get_where('st_dak_details',array('dakLetterNo'=>$letterno));
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('st_dak_details');
      $this->db->like('dakLetterNo', $letterno); //'%l/54%'
      $query= $this->db->get();
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
      } else {
            return array();
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the endeavor you are putting into to solve the code issue for stranger like me, a big salute from me for your kindness. However, when I executed your code I got following error like: Message: Illegal string offset 'dakLetterNo'

Filename: userManagement/forward2.php

Line Number: 20

Comment: Illegal string offset 'dakLetterNo is in view page.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: :Thanks, I have used return $query->result_array(); instead of return $query->row();in view page and it seems to work. Thank you, may god bless u for investing your time to improve our code and lives.